# Why is Windows Task Scheduler starting my tasks early?

Tags: windows, task-scheduler

I made a task in Windows that's supposed to run 10 minutes after the hour every hour. However, when I look at the task in the task scheduler, it will say it ran at XX:09:59 instead of XX:10:00. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2hHz.png):

[image]

You can see that I created the task at 12:10. The last time the tas ran was 2:09:59. The next scheduled task is 3:10:10. This isn't a problem because I don't really care when the task runs as long as it's once an hour. I was just wondering why this is happening. I am on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Did you have it specificly set to "at task creation/modification"? When you mention the time it was created? . (what was the designation for "begin the task")  . Did you put in a Delay?  I thought mabey delay was offset them here and there so they would not all work "on the moment of the hour" ?

Comment: @Psycogeek: I created the task before 12:10. I set it to begin the task at 12:10 and to repeat every hour.

Comment: Did You set the "begin the task"  "on a schedule" ?

Comment: @Psycogeek: Yes.

Comment: well this is off-topic, but dont you worry that using the "schedule" it will not start at all because the time is passed or not there yet?  I dont fully understand it myself, I am just interested in using it again for other things.  If the only interest that it run once an hour, I have been using the "at startup" because I dont know how either.

Comment: I see now, that the "time sync" item (example) which has been effectivly operating daily, was set as a "schedule" to start back in 2005 :-) . That explains why it takes a big screw-up before these "scheduled" tasks ever failed on people. Like when the computer was accidentally set back to 1999 , and other way-off issues where it failed for people?  I have now set some things for "schedule Hour+10minutes", in schedule (not delay), and I will see when it actually occurs.

Comment: ^ after having a schedule set for 1:10 daily, it occured at 1:10 as it should (I did not observe this problem yet), now I am going to test hourly.